# In Excel, way to enter multiple array list elements into a single cell, then sort by them?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have a column that I want to contain 1 or more tag values, e.g.:

```
row1:    X
row2:    Y
row3:    X, Y
row4:    X, Z
row5:    X, Y, Z
```

And then, when I auto-filter on that column, I want my filtering options to simply be:

```
X
Y
Z
```

i.e. if I filter by X, then I should see rows 1, 3, 4, and 5 from above.  This, instead of just seeing row 1.

Is such a setup possible?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Auto-Filter and Custom Auto-Filter might help.

A nice tutorial can be found here: [Excel AutoFilter Makes Spreadsheets More Useful](http://www.timeatlas.com/5_minute_tips/general/excel_autofilter_makes_spreadsheets_more_useful).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the auto filter part, there definitely will be a VB Find code for it...

Having said that, would the `IF(IsError(Search...` be of any use to you? Something along the lines under

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("x",A1,1)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("y",A1,1)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("z",A1,1)),"Other","z"),"y"),"x")
```